# How to remove the css class

Tags: c#, asp.net, css

I have a piece of code that is wrapped in a css class, the problem is that there is one particular line there that needs to be in the `<span>` but does not need the css class. How can I tell it to not take that css? for that line

```
<span id="myPrice" class="Price" runat="server">  
    <uc:CustomMessage ID="mPrice" MessageKey="myMsg" runat="server" /> //does not need css
    <span ><asp:Literal ID="litPrice" runat="server" /></span>
</span>
```

So as you can see the second line, we dont want the css applied to it.. but it needs to be within that "myPrice" span.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a design standpoint it would be better to move the styling to the inner `<span>` instead, but if that's not possible you could probably exclude it like this:

```
.Price:not(input[type="button"]) { color:red; }
```

The above excludes buttons, but you can replace this with whatever element you need. Here's a more detailed reference:

http://kilianvalkhof.com/2008/css-xhtml/the-css3-not-selector/

Answer (score 0):

Give your user control its own CSS class, and specify rules that undo the effect of `Price`.

```
<uc:CustomMessage CssClass="noStyles" ID="mPrice" MessageKey="myMsg" runat="server" />
```

Then, have a rule called `noStyles` that undoes any effects of `Price`.

Answer (score 0):

Can you apply the css rule just to the first line ?

```
#myPrice #mPrice { your rule }
```